# If I launch a group of task to be executed in an event loop asyncio, can I react to the return of each separately?

Tags: subprocess, python-asyncio

I want to launch 10 OS subprocess with asyncio. I can do that with gather for example and then I can  find out at the end of the event loop, the status of each tasks. But I have to wait for the whole thing to finish. Even when each task run concurrently.
Is there a way to know that subprocess 1 already finished and react to that event, even before the other 9 tasks have completed?

I am working with Python >3.7 (3.8.6 and 3.9.1).

Maybe my question should be:  Once that the event loop is running. Is there a way to find out the status of the tasks being running?

Or, the way it is expected that the task itself would do any after work after the await statement is completed but before returning and leaving the event loop.

I'll try that approach. In the meantime this is the code I am using for my basic testings:

Example of what I want:

```
import time


async def osrunner(cmd):
    proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(
          cmd,
          stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
          stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE)

    stdout, stderr = await proc.communicate()
    if stdout:
      print(f'[stdout]\n{stdout.decode()}')
    if stderr:
      print(f'[stderr]\n{stderr.decode()}')
    return True





async def main():

    cmd00='sleep 35'
    cmd01='sleep 15'
    cmd02='sleep 25'
    cmd03='sleep 5'

    task0 = asyncio.create_task( osrunner(cmd00) )
    task1 = asyncio.create_task( osrunner(cmd01) )
    task2 = asyncio.create_task( osrunner(cmd02) )
    task3 = asyncio.create_task( osrunner(cmd03) )


    await task0
    await task1
    await task2
    await task3



print(f"started main at {time.strftime('%X')}")
asyncio.run(main())               #<------------------I want to poll the status of the tasks and do something while the others are still unfinished
print(f"finished main  at {time.strftime('%X')}")
```

Comment: I solved the issue by doing what I thought, by letting the job to do whatever it needs to be done before returning.  That way the caller (asyncio.run(main()) can block and everything would be taken care by each separate task.  At the end of the main function I can email, or notifiy the status code of all the jobs at once.   My question  still is relevant,  Can I do it by polling the event loop?

Comment: It's hard to tell what you mean by "poll the event loop". If you control the `main` function, you can certainly react to individual tasks finishing, e.g. using `add_done_callback`, or by awaiting them using `as_completed`.

Comment: When you do the asycio.run(main())  you lose control until the full set of tasks are completed....I wanted to be able to know when one of the task was completed, even when it was the first one and only one, do something about it and keep on watching other tasks status.

Comment: But you don't lose control - for example, after `await task0` the control returns back to `main()`. Or do you count as "control" only if it happens in the sync code?

Comment: Exactly.  I wanted, probably because I did not know better to start the event loop, let 
 the event loop, take care of the coroutines  and still be able to monitor the status of each of the task being executed in the event loop.  Did I make myself clearer?   Thank you

Comment: You can't control it from sync code because sync code blocked on `asyncio.run(...)`. (You could use multiple threads, but that complicates things and shouldn't be done without an extremely good reason.) Instead, you can place your control inside `main` and react to individual tasks finishing, as described in my first comment. At this point it's not clear what is your actual requirement.

Comment: It seems that when I asked the question I was really confused on how the whole thing works.  If you notice my first comment after the initial question, I had already realized how to work around that issue.  You have confirmed that I am in the right path now.  Thank you for that.

Answer (score 0):

You want [`asyncio.as_completed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.as_completed). It returns an iterator you can loop over, which yields each item as it completes. Example code from the official docs:

```
for coro in as_completed(aws):
    earliest_result = await coro
    # ...
```